# TclError: wrong # args error

Tags: python-2.7, tkinter

I have no idea what is wrong but I keep getting this

> Exception in Tkinter callback
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 1410, in **call**
>       return self.func(*args)
>     File "/Users/Zane/Desktop/Factorial GUI.py", line 72, in reveal2
>       self.text2.insert(0.0, message)
>     File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/7.3/lib/python2.7/lib-tk/Tkinter.py", line 2986, in insert
>       self.tk.call((self._w, 'insert', index, chars) + args)
>   TclError: wrong # args: should be ".22186144.22187184 insert index chars ?tagList chars tagList ...?"

here is my code:`

```
from Tkinter import*

class App(Frame):

def fac(self, n):

    if n >= 0:
        if n == 1 or n == 0:
            return 1
        else:
            return n*self.fac(n-1)
    else:
        print('Error')

def per(self, n, r):

    y = (self.fac(n)) / self.fac(n - r)
    print (y)


def __init__(self, master):

    Frame.__init__(self,master)
    self.grid()
    self.create_widgets()

def create_widgets(self):
    self.instruction1 = Label(self, text = "Factorial:")
    self.instruction1.grid(row = 0, column = 0, columnspan = 1, sticky = W)

    self.password1 = Entry(self)
    self.password1.grid(row = 0, column = 1, sticky = W)

    self.submit_button1 = Button(self, text ="Enter", command = self.reveal1)
    self.submit_button1.grid(row = 2, column = 0, sticky = W)

    self.text1 = Text(self, width = 30, height = 1, wrap = WORD)
    self.text1.grid(row = 3, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

    self.instruction2 = Label(self, text = "Permutation:")
    self.instruction2.grid(row = 4, column = 0, columnspan = 1, sticky = W)

    self.password2 = Entry(self)
    self.password2.grid(row = 4, column = 1, sticky = W)

    self.password3 = Entry(self)
    self.password3.grid(row = 6, column = 1, sticky = W)

    self.submit_button2 = Button(self, text ="Enter", command = self.reveal2)
    self.submit_button2.grid(row = 7, column = 0, sticky = W)

    self.text2 = Text(self, width = 30, height = 1, wrap = WORD)
    self.text2.grid(row = 8, column = 0, columnspan = 2, sticky = W)

def reveal1(self):

    y = int(self.password1.get())

    message = self.fac(y)

    self.text1.delete(0.0, END)
    self.text1.insert(0.0, message)

def reveal2(self):

    y = int(self.password2.get())
    z = int(self.password3.get())

    message = self.per(y, z)

    self.text2.delete(0.0, END)
    self.text2.insert(0.0, message)


root = Tk()
root.title('Factorial')
root.geometry("340x300")
app = App(root)

root.mainloop()
```

`

Comment: Also when I hit the enter button (which creates the error) the correct answer prints in the console but not in the entry box.

Comment: It should be harmless, but `0.0` is an illegal index; text widget indexes start with 1.0.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Almost the only way to get the error you say you get with the code you posted, is if the `insert` method is called when the data to insert is `None`. `message` comes from the result of `per`, but `per` returns `None` because you don't explicitly return anything else.

One of the first things to try when trying to debug is to check that the data you're sending to the failing function is what you think it is. You can do this in a very low-tech way by simply printing out the values being passed to the `insert` message. This instantly told me that `message` was `None`. Once I learned that, it's pretty simple to answer the question "why was it None?".

Comment: Um okay but answering a question with a question is not what I was looking for. I figured it out myself by the way.

Comment: @zlittrell: I don't understand your comment. I didn't answer the question with a question. I told you specifically what the problem was (per returns None), and I also told you how I came to that conclusion.

Comment: Saying that it returns None was not what I was asking for however, I just wanted to know how to fix the problem

Comment: @zlittrell: ... ? You said you have no idea what is wrong and I told you precisely what was wrong. I also told you how I figured that out. What could I have said to make this more useful?

Comment: @BryanOakley I am having a similar problem but with `delete`, not `insert`: `self.tk.call(self._w, 'delete', first, last)`. Do you know what generally causes this? I may have to start a new thread on this but I'm afraid it may backfire. I can't post my codes: it's very long with many modules. I tried to recreate the error in fewer lines of code by my recreation works fine with no error. Confusing.

Comment: @sedeh: I don't know how to answer you. Tkinter is rock solid in its implementation. If you're getting a similar error, you're doing something wrong. Without seeing what you're doing, it's impossible for me to even guess. You need to step through your code line-by-line, validating all of your assumptions (ie: is the index correct, is there data at that index? etc.).

Comment: @BryanOakley Sure. I think I resolved the problem. I think I had two listboxes that weren't uniquely named and so the callback was confused. Please could you lend your voice to my tkinter question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25415888/default-to-and-select-first-item-in-tkinter-listbox). You seem to understand tkinter like no other. Thanks.